# How can I filter all the rows of my dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science

my data frame is an election stat =>  its containing ages of voters and 6 parties with percentages

[image]

After that i filter the data frame by the age => i filter all the age below 18
i got a new data frame.
now i got all the voters that are more than 18

```
    df_election_filter1 = self.election
    filter_below_age = df_election_filter1.age > 18
    print( df_election_filter1[filter_below_age] )
    df = df_election_filter1[filter_below_age]
```

Now i want to filter in my data frame all the parties that have score value below 0.2
how can I do it ? for each parties i need to be more than 0.2

Comment: What's a score value?

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
df = df.loc[(df['Column1'] > 0.2) | (df['Column2'] > 0.2), :] # you can add other columns if needed
```

In this code you select all rows whose values  are larger than 0.2 in columns 'Column1' or 'Column2'. You can add more columns, e.g. for each of the parties.

Using your column names:

```
df = df.loc[(df['HopeforChange'] > 0.2) | (df['WeWillWin'] > 0.2) | (df[etc] > 0.2), :] # fill etc with other columns
```

Let me know if this is not what you need.

Comment: now how can i  Separate results into an Excel file for each party which will contain all voter ids with a score of >0.2 and age>18

Comment: Do you mean, save the results into an excel file? If so, you might try `df.to_csv('file_name.csv')`. Replace 'file_name' by your desired file name.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all columns except the age column and query the data:

```
df.loc[:, df.columns != 'age'] >= 0.2
```